# Render directory structure data with n numbers of levels in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a sample data set of directory structure as follows

http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=f9ce34de42f1a395e172f81c0c850da1

Similar to directories the level can be of n numbers.

In react I want to create a directory structure using this data with onClick event.
For example on the first page the root directories children should be displayed, and when I click on first child, first child's children should be displayed.

[image]

This is what I want, initially only 3 folders were visible at root level.

[image]

When I clicked on child2 at level 1 other two children got visible,

[image: sample Image]

and when again clicked on child 2 its 2 children were visible.
Now if I click any other directory its children should be visible.

Can you please suggest me the correct way to get it implemented in reactJs with redux?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Directory` component which will recursively render by passing its children through props to a new `Directory` component.  I've created a [JS fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mark1z/j8fk6bbq/1) to demonstrate, with the code below.  This example does not use redux, but you can still apply this approach.

```
var DirectoryRoot = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    var sample_dir = {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "P1",
          "children": [{
            "id": 2,
            "name": "C1_P1",
            "children": [{
              "id": 3,
              "name": "C1_C1_P1"
            }, {
              "id": 4,
              "name": "C2_C1_P1",
              "children": [{
                "id": 5,
                "name": "C1_C2_C1_P1"
              }, {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "C2_C2_C1_P1"
              }]
            }]
          }, {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "C2_P1"
          }, {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "C3_P1",
            "children": [{
              "id": 8,
              "name": "C1_C3_P1",
              "children": [{
                "id": 10,
                "name": "C1_C1_C3_P1",
                "children": [{
                  "name": "C1_C1_C1_C3_P1"
                }]
              }]
            }]
          }]
        }
    return {dirs: sample_dir, clicked: false};
  },
  handleClick: function(){
    this.setState({clicked: !this.state.clicked});
  },
  render: function() {
    var sub_dirs = this.state.dirs.children.map(function(dir){
      return <Directory dirs={dir}/>
    }.bind(this));
    console.log(this.state.dirs)
    return (<div onClick={this.handleClick}> 
      <div>Root {this.state.dirs.name} </div>
      {this.state.clicked ?
        <div style={{marginLeft:10}}> {sub_dirs} </div> : null
      }

    </div>) 
    //return <div> {this.recursiveDirRender(this.state.dirs)}</div>;
  }
});

var Directory = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {clicked: false}
  },
  handleClick: function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.setState({clicked: !this.state.clicked})
  },
  render: function(){
    console.log(this.props.dirs)
    var sub_dirs = this.props.dirs.children ?this.props.dirs.children.map(function(dir){
      return (<div key={dir.key}>
          <Directory dirs={dir}/> 
      </div>)
    }.bind(this)) : null;


    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.props.dirs.name}
        <div style={{marginLeft: 20, display: (this.state.clicked ? null: "none")}}> {sub_dirs} </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <DirectoryRoot/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: This is great solution, even I was heading towards the recursive component rendering.
Hey can you suggest me how do I maintain the state of one component redux?
As to maintain the clicked state for directory component.

Comment: You could add a clicked key/value to each of the directories in the JSON before you set it as state in the store. You would need to create an action that would change the proper clicked state in the directory tree.